# How can I add data to the first row of a table before it is filled with MPmedia items from a query?

Tags: swift, collections, tableview, xcode9, mpmediaquery

I have been slowly building a music player.  I query album data to populate a table.  If the user selects an album, we segue to a new screen to pick a song to play.  I'd like to make the first row of the albums table (in the albums view controller), be a row called 'All Songs', but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

I have tried to use: insertRowsAtIndexPaths.  But was unsuccessful.

```
    @IBOutlet var albumsTableView: UITableView!

    let qryAlbums = MPMediaQuery.albums()  // Query the albums

    // Set the cell in the table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // I am using the custom class that I created called: myCustomAlbumTableViewCell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "albumIdCell", for: indexPath) as! myCustomAlbumTableViewCell

        let rowItem = qryAlbums.collections![indexPath.row]

        cell.albumTitle.text = rowItem.items[0].albumTitle

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that you are displaying one more row than you have query albums and then every time you need to get a query album you minus 1 from the indexPath.row

```
    @IBOutlet var albumsTableView: UITableView!

    let qryAlbums = MPMediaQuery.albums()  // Query the albums

    // Set the cell in the table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // I am using the custom class that I created called: myCustomAlbumTableViewCell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "albumIdCell", for: indexPath) as! myCustomAlbumTableViewCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.albumTitle.text = "All Songs"
        } else {

            let rowItem = qryAlbums.collections![indexPath.row-1]

            cell.albumTitle.text = rowItem.items[0].albumTitle
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->  Int {
        return qryAlbums.collections! .count + 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row > 0 {
            let rowItem = qryAlbums.collections![indexPath.row-1]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  It is partially working.  The user has to be able to select that first row ("All Songs").  Then when I segue to the next view controller, I know to list all the songs from all the albums by that artist.  For example, if an artist has 4 albums in the music library on the device, I list "All Songs", followed by the titles of the 4 albums.  In testing, the first 4 rows work, but the fifth crashes.

Comment: I have been using didSelectRowAtIndexPath...    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "rowSelectedGotoSongsVC", sender: tableView)
    }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You have 5 rows in your tableView. The first is "All Songs". The other 4 are album titles. From what I understand this is working and displaying correctly. But if you tap on the last row the app crashes? it sounds like you aren't subtracting 1 from the indexPath.row when getting the actual row Item: let rowItem = qryAlbums.collections![indexPath.row-1]

Comment: You are correct!  I had subtracted the 1 from the place that you said (inside cellForRowAtIndexPath), but forgot to do so in the code that handles the segue (I forgot to post that section yesterday).  Anyway, while I need to do more testing, your solution works.  Thank you very much for helping me out!!!